# Magento 2. Installation full release with simple data

Tags: magento2, magento-community

Hi have been trying to install magento 2 package full release with simple data buto unsuccessfully.

I thought I just had to download the package. Unzip it and follow the 5 steps wizard installation. But despite seeing a successfully installation at the end admin does not exist. Front end has no template....

- I did it on wamp 2.5 on windows 7.
- All requirement met on readNess checking page.

If someone else tried successfully thanks to exchange me the steps used.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you enabled [Apache server rewrites](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html#apache-help-rewrite).

Second, try downloading the [zip file with sample data already in it](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html#get-archive). That is the easiest way to install it.

Answer (score 0):

- Admin does not exist: maybe you entered wrong backend url, you can check it in `app/etc/env.php` line 5.
- In my way, after install finished wizard installation, I ran `composer init`, then ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US` to deploy frontend and backend css, js, images in root Magento folder.